# Javascript loop variable

Tags: javascript, concatenation

I want to get values from textboxes. I have this Javascript code:

```
var lines = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < equation; i++) {
    var s = document.getElementById("row"+i).value;
    lines[i] = s;
}
```

In the loop i can't concatenate "row" and i loop variable. If I declare a j variable, the concatenation is good, but when I try to increment j, it has an error (doesn't run).

```
var lines = new Array();
var j = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < equation; i++) {
    var s = document.getElementById("row"+j).value;
    lines[i] = s;
    j++;
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: What error message are you getting? That doesn't look syntactically incorrect to me at a glance.

Comment: With this code as-written, every entry is `lines` is going to be the last `row`.

Comment: there must be other code not shown causing problems....is this loop inside another loop?

Comment: First code works now, but after the loop no other code runs (example: alert("text");).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of targeting with index you could just push the entrys into array

```
var lines = [];
for (var i = 0; i < equation; i++) {
    var s = document.getElementById("row"+i).value;
    lines.push(s);
    console.log(lines) 
}
```

and be sure `equation` exists and it´s a number and its not bigger than all your rows #row*

Comment: And all those row# id elements should exist. If not he will get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null`

Comment: @Anton, yes thats what i mean! "equation" must be the amount of all existing rows or less

Comment: I can display values of s with alert() in loop but after the loop the other code lines doesn't work even if the other code only is an alert();

Comment: never use alerts to debug a loop, use console logging instead, alerts may interrupt the whole thing like you described. updated answer

Comment: The problem is: if I increment equation outside of this function, no code works after the loop. When I don't increment, it works fine.